# When the user tries to Delete any of the row, It is taking 5 seconds time to display the Confirmation popup in IE browser

Tags: internet-explorer, angular8

[when i click on the delete icon as shown in the image confirmation pop is taking 5seconds time to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR2NI.png)

deletecomponent.html

```
    <p-column header="Action" [style]="{'width':'20%','text-align':'center'}">
    <ng-template let-rowData="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-bg bg-red" title="Delete" style="cursor:pointer;"
    (click)="confirmDelete(rowData)"></i></ng-template></p-column>
```

deletecomponent.ts

```
    async confirmDelete(rowData) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({                
    message: "Delete " + rowData.STR_COMMUNICATION_TYPE + " notification for "+rowData.CLASS_NAME +
              "?",
            accept: async () => {
                this.growlMessage = [];
                if (this.blnShowOrgGroupLabel == true) {
                    this.orgGroupIDForDBUpdate = this.orgGrpID;
                }
                else {
                    this.orgGroupIDForDBUpdate = this.selectedOrgGroupId;
                }
                let CLASS_ID = rowData.CLASS_ID;
                let CMP_TYPE = rowData.COMMUNICATION_TYPE;
                let FUNC_TYPE = rowData.FUNCTION_NAME;
                let ORG_GROUP_ID = this.orgGroupIDForDBUpdate;
                this.spinnerService.start();
                await this._LotNotificationSetupService.DeleteRowData(CLASS_ID, CMP_TYPE, FUNC_TYPE, 
                ORG_GROUP_ID)
                    .catch(this.httpService.handleError).then((res) => {
                        let response = res as AtParWebApiResponse<MT_ATPAR_LOT_NOTIFICATION_DETAILS>;
                        this.statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                        this.spinnerService.stop();
            });
            },
            reject: () => {
                this.spinnerService.stop();
                return;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can try to use [F12 dev tools Performance tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/bg182326(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#the-ui-responsiveness-tool-ctrl--5) to check which part slows down your app. Besides, Microsoft announced that [IE 11 desktop application will be retired on June 15, 2022](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/), I think you can move to Edge as soon as possible.